# qt - How to add radio button to a QMainWindow

Tags: qt

I am creating a small window to get a single input from user. For this I want to use radio buttons. In net I didn't find exact answer. There are some pallets they are adding, so just I want to know how to add `QRadioButton` to `QMainWindow`. Can any body help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply specifies the parent (your `QMainWindow`) when creating the RadioButton

```
QMainWindow *w = new QMainWindow();
QRadioButton *radiobutton = new QRadioButton(w);
w->show();
```

More @ http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qradiobutton.html